# Orthogonal complements in exterior powers

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Consider the standard induced inner product structure on $\wedge^k\mathbb{R}^d$ given by defining $$\langle u_1\wedge \cdots \wedge u_k, v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_k\rangle:=\det ([\langle u_i, v_j\rangle]_{i,j=1}^d)$$
for simple $k$-vectors and extending to general $k$-vectors in the obvious fashion.

If a linear subspace $W$ of $\wedge^k \mathbb{R}^d$ admits a basis of simple $k$-vectors, does its orthogonal complement have the same property?

Comment: Just an example, not an answer: $$W=\text{span}\{e_1\wedge e_2,\;(e_1\cos\alpha+e_3\sin\alpha)\wedge(e_2\cos\beta+e_4\sin\beta)\}\;\subset\;\wedge^2\mathbb R^4$$ $$W^\perp=\text{span}\{e_1\wedge e_3,\;e_2\wedge e_4,\;(-e_1\sin\alpha+e_3\cos\alpha)\wedge e_4,\;e_3\wedge(-e_2\sin\beta+e_4\cos\beta)\}$$